# No such file or directory '/Users/qt/work/qt/qtbase'

Tags: ios, qt

Hi I'm trying to run a Qt app on iOS Simulator. However, I am getting this error. Image is attached, please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: You usually don't have access to `/Users/qt` when using the simulator. You probably need to move your `qt` folder to the bundle and link it properly (or just link it properly if you already did the first part).

Comment: It was an issue with the Qt Qmake when I compile the app for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the problem with the Qt6 qmake. On macOS, I don't know why, but it generates the wrong path for the library files when I compile the app for iOS. I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645194/qt6-qmake-for-ios-generates-incorrect-paths-to-standard-libraries) post and solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).